# Is there a way from SQLITE to Java annotated classes?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I am in the process of migrating my hand-coded database code under Android to an ORM-based environment. I think they are now mature enough to provide different alternatives for my work. Taking into consideration that I have not chosen one yet, I wanted to ask if there exists something that allows to convert a SQLITE eschema into the corresponding Java classes (whether annotated or not, although a ready-to-use annotated class would be much better). My database is quite simple, without complex types or relationships, being the most complex a many to many table.

Any hints on this or how to perform it in a productive manner?.

EDIT: I have make a thorough search on the Internet for something like this and stackoverflow is the last resort I have considered. This is for those voting negatively without giving a reason. Thanks and sorry for the inconveniences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I wanted to ask if there exists something that* then your question is off-topic ... *any suggestions regarding an ORM framework for Android?* and primarily opinion-based

Comment: @Selvin, you are right, the second question is out of place... It was a "just in case", I will delete it. The first one I think is on-topic by the way... How if not could I get the help I am looking for?. Please, send me suggestions because I always seem to hit a wall here at SO...

Comment: off-topic: *Questions asking us to recommend or **find a** book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* ... SO is not human search engine ...

Comment: @Selvin, thanks a lot for the clarification. But after all, I supposed this is a support community. If I cannot find a way to do things, why cannot I ask other expert people for help?.

Comment: I think @Kankamuso question is valid and should not be closed.

Comment: Thanks @MurtazaKhursheedHussain. Many times I feel like this site is a bit chaotic regarding what is right or wrong to be posted here. It is frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution right here. It didn't seem a dumb question right then...

[How to generate orm mapping classes from sql schema in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939667/how-to-generate-orm-mapping-classes-from-sql-schema-in-java)